r - ggplot connects geom_ribbons that with thin line in PDF
I'm trying to plot a geom_ribbon object that is disconnected from other geom_ribbon objects. This perfectly works for the RStudio internal display and saving png files, but the geom_ribbon objects are connected with very thin lines when using a PDF.
This is the plot:
ggplot(data = b,
       aes(x = time,
           y = fitted)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = cf_lwr, ymax = cf_upr, fill = "red", 
                  group = .data$name),na.rm = FALSE) + 
  facet_wrap(~id) -> test
test


But when I now try to save it as a PDF:
ggsave(test, filename = "Test1.pdf")

I get very thin lines connecting the ribbon items (zoomed in) in the resulting PDF:


I have tried playing around with setting na.rm = TRUE and na.rm = FALSE and have also removed the group argument, but to no avail.
Similarly, I've tried to use geom_polygon() but there I'm struggling as well:
b %>% 
  select(-fitted) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(time,name,id), names_to = "type", values_to = "value") %>% 

ggplot(aes(x = time,
           y = value,
           group = name)) +
  geom_polygon(fill = "red") + 
  facet_wrap(~id)


Any ideas? Thanks for your help!!
Data:
b <- structure(list(time = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
                             12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
                             11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18), 
                    fitted = c(9.82399931488347, 
                               9.83890547549997, 9.96835827682772, 10.0015563715667, 10.0195513075349, 
                               10.0263620267794, 10.0281679132439, 10.0402091409343, 10.0258148087331, 
                               9.98957105642021, 9.98927729804064, 9.98360672736602, 9.93408407605121, 
                               10.0055066926455, 9.99807441172596, 10.0103947595883, 10.0307184111839, 
                               10.0341349325091, 10.037783284132, 12.0002972837409, 12.0165016808134, 
                               12.0186694303305, 11.9094084266171, 11.9169384086629, 11.9142773254232, 
                               11.9152467227305, 11.9196906398965, 11.9019674827009, 11.8605280898209, 
                               11.8717838389661, 11.873563656638, 11.911828082864, 11.9084315759843, 
                               11.9097428414989, 11.9254137346769, 11.9445590081518, 11.9455459935057, 
                               11.9416905527665), 
                    cf_lwr = c(9.82399931488347, 9.83890547549997, 
                               9.90572544776573, 9.93892354250466, 9.95691847847286, 9.9637291977174, 
                               9.9655350841819, 9.97757631187226, 10.0258148087331, 9.98957105642021, 
                               9.98927729804064, 9.98360672736602, 9.93408407605121, 9.96308021671443, 
                               9.95564793579493, 9.96796828365724, 9.98829193525292, 9.99170845657809, 
                               9.99535680820095, 12.0002972837409, 12.0165016808134, 12.0186694303305, 
                               12.0893867811635, 12.0969167632093, 12.0942556799696, 12.0952250772769, 
                               12.0996689944429, 12.0819458372473, 11.8605280898209, 11.8717838389661, 
                               11.873563656638, 11.8641739911823, 11.8607774843026, 11.8620887498172, 
                               11.8777596429952, 11.8969049164701, 11.897891901824, 11.9416905527665
                    ), 
                    cf_upr = c(9.82399931488347, 9.83890547549997, 9.79995528174166, 
                               9.83315337648059, 9.85114831244879, 9.85795903169334, 9.85976491815783, 
                               9.8718061458482, 10.0258148087331, 9.98957105642021, 9.98927729804064, 
                               9.98360672736602, 9.93408407605121, 9.89219474605896, 9.88476246513946, 
                               9.89708281300177, 9.91740646459744, 9.92082298592262, 9.92447133754548, 
                               12.0002972837409, 12.0165016808134, 12.0186694303305, 11.9953346595386, 
                               12.0028646415844, 12.0002035583447, 12.001172955652, 12.005616872818, 
                               11.9878937156224, 11.8605280898209, 11.8717838389661, 11.873563656638, 
                               11.7806377756053, 11.7772412687256, 11.7785525342402, 11.7942234274183, 
                               11.8133687008931, 11.8143556862471, 11.9416905527665), 
                    name = c(NA, 
                             "groupB2002", "groupB2002", "groupB2002", "groupB2002", "groupB2002", 
                             "groupB2002", "groupB2002", NA, NA, NA, NA, "groupB2013", "groupB2013", 
                             "groupB2013", "groupB2013", "groupB2013", "groupB2013", "groupB2013", 
                             NA, NA, "groupB2003", "groupB2003", "groupB2003", "groupB2003", 
                             "groupB2003", "groupB2003", "groupB2003", NA, NA, "groupB2012", 
                             "groupB2012", "groupB2012", "groupB2012", "groupB2012", "groupB2012", 
                             "groupB2012", NA), 
                    id = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
                           "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", 
                           "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
                           "B", "B", "B", "B", "B")), 
               row.names = c(NA, -38L), class = "data.frame") 

Session Info:
R version 4.3.0 (2023-04-21 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 11 x64 (build 22631)

Matrix products: default


locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Austria.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_Austria.utf8    LC_MONETARY=English_Austria.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                    
[5] LC_TIME=English_Austria.utf8    

time zone: Europe/Vienna
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] forcats_1.0.0   stringr_1.5.0   purrr_1.0.2     readr_2.1.4     tidyr_1.3.0     tibble_3.2.1    tidyverse_2.0.0 getspanel_0.2.0 padr_0.6.2     
[10] lubridate_1.9.2 dplyr_1.1.2     ggplot2_3.4.4   testthat_3.1.8 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rdpack_2.5        remotes_2.4.2     sandwich_3.0-2    rlang_1.1.1       magrittr_2.0.3    compiler_4.3.0    systemfonts_1.0.4 callr_3.7.3      
 [9] vctrs_0.6.3       profvis_0.3.8     pkgconfig_2.0.3   shape_1.4.6       crayon_1.5.2      fastmap_1.1.1     ellipsis_0.3.2    labeling_0.4.2   
[17] utf8_1.2.3        promises_1.2.0.1  tzdb_0.4.0        sessioninfo_1.2.2 ps_1.7.5          miscTools_0.6-28  ragg_1.2.5        glmnet_4.1-8     
[25] cachem_1.0.8      collapse_1.9.6    later_1.3.1       parallel_4.3.0    prettyunits_1.1.1 R6_2.5.1          stringi_1.7.12    pkgload_1.3.4    
[33] brio_1.1.3        lmtest_0.9-40     Rcpp_1.0.10       iterators_1.0.14  usethis_2.2.0     zoo_1.8-12        timechange_0.2.0  httpuv_1.6.11    
[41] Matrix_1.6-5      splines_4.3.0     tidyselect_1.2.0  rstudioapi_0.14   maxLik_1.5-2      codetools_0.2-19  miniUI_0.1.1.1    processx_3.8.1   
[49] pkgbuild_1.4.0    lattice_0.21-8    shiny_1.7.4       withr_2.5.0       gets_0.37         fastDummies_1.6.3 desc_1.4.2        survival_3.5-5   
[57] urlchecker_1.0.1  pillar_1.9.0      rsconnect_1.1.0   foreach_1.5.2     generics_0.1.3    rprojroot_2.0.3   hms_1.1.3         munsell_0.5.0    
[65] scales_1.2.1      xtable_1.8-4      glue_1.6.2        tools_4.3.0       data.table_1.14.8 fs_1.6.2          mvtnorm_1.2-2     grid_4.3.0       
[73] rbibutils_2.2.15  bdsmatrix_1.3-6   devtools_2.4.5    colorspace_2.1-0  nlme_3.1-162      Formula_1.2-5     cli_3.6.1         textshaping_0.3.6
[81] plm_2.6-3         fansi_1.0.4       gtable_0.3.3      digest_0.6.31     htmlwidgets_1.6.2 farver_2.1.1      memoise_2.0.1     htmltools_0.5.5  
[89] lifecycle_1.0.3   mime_0.12         MASS_7.3-58.4 


What code are you using to save as pdf?

Apologies will add above - but super simply: ggsave(test, filename = "Test1.pdf")

I can't reproduce this (macOS, ggplot2 v3.5.1), but perhaps try ggsave(test, filename = "Test1.pdf", device = cairo_pdf) and see if you get the same issue
